# How to get Unix offsets from sequelize?

Tags: node.js, date, timestamp, sequelize.js

I’m using sequelize in node using Postgres. I have TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIMEZONE fields but they always come back as strings. I want Unix offsets. I like using native date formats but strings are useless to me.

Is there a standard pattern for getting just the offset? Or do I just change everything to integers in the DB?

I’m also happy with millisecond offsets.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want the offset you should have a integer filed in your table to store it, you can get the date offset like this:

```
let offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset

But if you want the Unix timestamp you can get it like beneath:

```
let ts = parseInt((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
```

Similar to this link: https://www.electrictoolbox.com/unix-timestamp-javascript/, and store in an either integer or varchar field.

Comment: This has nothing to do with timezones.
Generating a unix offset is easy. I personally use: Math.floor(+new Date() / 1000) or just use milliseconds from +new Date() if that works. Your parseInt, I suspect, is a typo.

My main issue here is that you generate, let's say, a token expiry time, as a unix offset. It's unambiguous, doesn't need timezone qualification, etc. You convert it to string (floating point maths!) for SQL, it then converts to integer and the same back. I just want the integer. There are SQL ways of doing it. Just wondering if Sequelize has already dealt with it.